# Linkage error when using Elasticsearch client in Spring WebApp

Tags: java, spring, jsp, elasticsearch

I have a problem when trying to include the Elasticsearch java client in my WebApp. I have the required dependencies and I am creating the client (As a simple test) in a initializing/destroying Spring bean like so:

```
    @Override
public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
    try {
        client = new TransportClient();
        InetSocketTransportAddress addr = new InetSocketTransportAddress("localhost", 9300);
        ((TransportClient) client).addTransportAddress(addr);
    } 
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
}
```

The corresponding destroy() will close the client.

Everything looks ok and the context starts fine however when accessing a JSP I receive the following exception:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/Fountain] threw           exception [Filter execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation in interface itable initialization: when resolving method "javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getOutputStream()Ljavax/servlet/ServletOutputStream;" the class loader (instance of org/apache/catalina/loader/WebappClassLoader) of the current class, javax/servlet/ServletResponseWrapper, and the class loader (instance of org/apache/catalina/loader/StandardClassLoader) for interface javax/servlet/ServletResponse have different Class objects for the type vlet/ServletOutputStream; used in the signature
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:186)
at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:181)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:581)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Jan 10, 2014 10:44:46 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "javax.servlet.jsp.JspFactory.getPageContext(Ljavax/servlet/Servlet;Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljava/lang/String;ZIZ)Ljavax/servlet/jsp/PageContext;" the class loader (instance of org/apache/jasper/servlet/JasperLoader) of the current class, org/apache/jsp/jsp/ajaxerror_jsp, and the class loader (instance of org/apache/catalina/loader/StandardClassLoader) for resolved class, javax/servlet/jsp/JspFactory, have different Class objects for the type t/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljava/lang/String;ZIZ)Ljavax/servlet/jsp/PageContext; used in the signature
at org.apache.jsp.jsp.ajaxerror_jsp._jspService(ajaxerror_jsp.java:59)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:489)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:467)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:412)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:201)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Jan 10, 2014 10:44:46 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve custom
SEVERE: Exception Processing ErrorPage[exceptionType=java.lang.Throwable,      location=/jsp/ajaxerror.jsp]
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "javax.servlet.jsp.JspFactory.getPageContext(Ljavax/servlet/Servlet;Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljava/lang/String;ZIZ)Ljavax/servlet/jsp/PageContext;" the class loader (instance of org/apache/jasper/servlet/JasperLoader) of the current class, org/apache/jsp/jsp/ajaxerror_jsp, and the class loader (instance of org/apache/catalina/loader/StandardClassLoader) for resolved class, javax/servlet/jsp/JspFactory, have different Class objects for the type t/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljava/lang/String;ZIZ)Ljavax/servlet/jsp/PageContext; used in the signature
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:549)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:455)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:489)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:467)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:412)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:201)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method    "javax.servlet.jsp.JspFactory.getPageContext(Ljavax/servlet/Servlet;Ljavax/servlet/ServletR equest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljava/lang/String;ZIZ)Ljavax/servlet/jsp/PageContext;" the class loader (instance of org/apache/jasper/servlet/JasperLoader) of the current class, org/apache/jsp/jsp/ajaxerror_jsp, and the class loader (instance of org/apache/catalina/loader/StandardClassLoader) for resolved class, javax/servlet/jsp/JspFactory, have different Class objects for the type t/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljava/lang/String;ZIZ)Ljavax/servlet/jsp/PageContext; used in the signature
at org.apache.jsp.jsp.ajaxerror_jsp._jspService(ajaxerror_jsp.java:130)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "javax.servlet.jsp.JspFactory.getPageContext(Ljavax/servlet/Servlet;Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljava/lang/String;ZIZ)Ljavax/servlet/jsp/PageContext;" the class loader (instance of org/apache/jasper/servlet/JasperLoader) of the current class, org/apache/jsp/jsp/ajaxerror_jsp, and the class loader (instance of org/apache/catalina/loader/StandardClassLoader) for resolved class, javax/servlet/jsp/JspFactory, have different Class objects for the type t/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljava/lang/String;ZIZ)Ljavax/servlet/jsp/PageContext; used in the signature
at org.apache.jsp.jsp.ajaxerror_jsp._jspService(ajaxerror_jsp.java:59)
... 25 more
```

Without this the context starts and will serve JSPs correctly.

Does anyone have any ideas what may be causing this? I'm assuming the elasticsearch client is using a class that the web-app required but instatiating it in a different classloader.

I've tried explicitly setting the classloader used by elastic search by using ImmutableSettings but this appears not to make any difference:

```
    ClassLoader contextClassLoader = thread.getContextClassLoader();
    try {
        //thread.setContextClassLoader(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
        Settings s = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder()
                .classLoader(contextClassLoader)
                .build();
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Just a note unrelated to the question, you could look at https://github.com/dadoonet/spring-elasticsearch for a spring factory for elasticsearch.

Comment: Hi, Thanks dadoonet - your project was my first choice, but I had the same problem which is why I'm using this stripped down version to isolate the issue. When I resolve it I'll switch to your factories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, managed to resolve this problem:

Get a ref to the tomcat 'common' classloader and passed this to the Elasticsearch client:

```
ClassLoader contextClassLoader = thread.getContextClassLoader();
try {
        Settings settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder().classLoader(contextClassLoader.getParent()).build();            
        client = new TransportClient(settings);
```

A side effect of this is that the names.txt file has to be moved from the elasticSearch jar to  somewhere on the 'common' classpath.

I still haven't tracked down why this issue is affecting my particular stack and not others but aim to do so and update here.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to create the elastcisearch client like this :

```
Settings settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder()
.put(“path.plugins”, “fakeDirectory:\\”)
.build();

TransportClient client = new TransportClient(settings);
```

I put a fake directory because ElasticSearch use it when it start to load all eclipse plugins but i d’ont know why !! (see org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService class).