# Elasticsearch causing java.lang.LinkageError with javax/servlet/FilterConfig on Tomcat 7

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, elasticsearch

I am using `Elasticsearch 1.1.1`, java client and server versions are the same. Unit tests all run fine. when i start tomcat server, it has:

```
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/apache/catalina/loader/WebappClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "javax/servlet/FilterConfig"
```

and before that error, there were a lot of the following:

```
2014-05-02 15:07:03,954 DEBUG o.e.plugins [localhost-startStop-1] [Corsair] [D:\eclipse-indigo\plugins\org.python.pydev.jython_2.7.0.2012080220\_site] directory does not exist.
```

a lot of that and with different folders

if i remove the code that uses `elasticsearch` and keeping the dependency in pom.xml, server starts fine. `WEB-INF/lib` and my app's classpath does not have a `servlet-api.jar`, its only in `TOMCAT_HOME/lib`

the part i set up an es client is as follow:

```
if (this.client == null) {

    this.client = new TransportClient(ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder().
            put("cluster.name", this.cluster).build());

    final String[] addresses = this.hosts.split(",");

    for (final String address : addresses) {

        final String trimmed = address.trim();
        final String[] tuple = trimmed.split(":");
        this.client.addTransportAddress(
                new InetSocketTransportAddress(tuple[0].trim(), Integer.valueOf(tuple[1].trim())));

    }

}
```

The same code is used for unit tests and it passes all tests.

Any pointer is much appreciated.

This seems to be relevent but haven't been provided a proper solution.

[Linkage error when using Elasticsearch client in Spring WebApp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21043128/linkage-error-when-using-elasticsearch-client-in-spring-webapp?rq=1)

FYI, I am also using Spring & Spring MVC 4.2.5.RELEASE, Tomcat version 7.0.40

UPDATE:

Thanks to this link http://lexxweb.co.uk/blog/?p=66, it turns out that it is one of the eclipse plugin which loads another version servlet-api, causing the LinkageError I've been getting.

Comment: are you removing the elsaticsearch jar only or you are rebuilding your war without the dependency? Looks like you have a different version of the `servlet-api` that is pulled somehow.

Comment: I only remove the code that uses elasticsearch, keeping the dependency in my classpath, and the server starts ok.

Comment: im quite sure i have only one servlet-api.jar in my classpath which is from tomcat, but that LinkageError does indicate otherwise. The strangest part is using the same dependencies but without Elasticsearch relevent code makes the server start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to this link http://lexxweb.co.uk/blog/?p=66, it turns out that it is one of the eclipse plugin which loads another version servlet-api, causing the LinkageError I've been getting.  After deleting the plugin, everything is good now